# How to get easygui to filter file list

Tags: python, easygui

I've been using easygui for opening files and other tasks on my project and generally it works great. When using the fileopenbox, however, I am not able to get it to show only files of a certain type.

In the code snippet below I was expecting to get a listing of only *.csv files but it gives me everything in the directory. I worry this is a bit inconvenient for users, and would like to be able to filter that for ease of use.

```
import easygui as eg 
infile = eg.fileopenbox(msg='Please locate the csv file',
                        title='Specify File', default='c:\data\det\*.csv')
refdata = pd.read_csv(infile)
```

Now, what I do get is close. In the bottom of the file open dialog, where you can select file type, it is preloaded with only two choices : all files (*.*) and csv files (*.csv) so my setting of the default parameter seems to be doing something, it just stops a bit short of what I want it to do (which is to filter the list to make it easier for the user).

Appreciate any tips on how to do that. If there's a way to do it that doesn't involve easygui, that's a good solution too as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Seem like this is unique to OS. In `Ubuntu`, your code runs fine, no difference with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
import easygui as eg 
infile = eg.fileopenbox(msg='Please locate the csv file',
                    title='Specify File', default='c:\data\det\*.csv',
                    filetypes='*.csv')
refdata = pd.read_csv(infile)
```

Comment: Thanks much! I guess  I must've missed that feature in the documentation/tutorials I consulted.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me how to remove the "All Files"? I want to specify the format of the files...